# Payment options do not display when https used only when http used

Tags: joomla, payment-processor

I'm using CiviCRM on Joomla.
Under http Membership and Event Registration pages are displayed completely including Payment Options (pay later is enable and Standard Paypal).

Under https the Payment Options section does not display.

Any hints?

Comment: is your site and your civicrm.settings.php set up to use http or https by default?

Comment: didn't know about civic.settings.php so the answer would be by default

Comment: I've been trying to set up CiviCRM using the Joomla backend. As far as I know I have configured things. But could have easily overlooked something.

Comment: Interestingly the format of the fields on the page changes as well. Under http the field names like last name display left of the corresponding entry field but with https the field label appears above. I went looking for css changes but couldn't easily locate them. Using JAPurity III by default.

Comment: I am probably not asking the right question, but i would not expect you to be able to pull up pages in both http and https, i would expect one to swop to the other hence I wonder if you have some problem upstream in terms of what your default is, ie http or https, and whether you then have your base url set to the right one

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that CiviCRM is looking for an AJAX callback with an absolute URL.  It'll go with what's in the Administer - System Settings - Resource URLs, which is in turn influenced by the base URL in civicrm.settings.php.  The solution is to have the same URL, with https, be in effect across your entire site.

For a number of reasons, including potential problems with your session ending when you follow an absolute URL to http from https or vice-versa, you should have your site use a single canonical URL, with everything else redirecting to it.  For example, you might decide that https://example.org is the proper URL.  You should set up redirects in Apache/Nginx to have http://example.org, https://www.example.org, and http://www.example.org all send a visitor to https://example.org.

Read more at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3233/44