# Administration Console

Tags: admin

After Civi 4.6.10 upgrade I can no longer access the Administer/Administration Console without getting an error.  Here is a sample:

@import url(/devjom3update/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/devjom3update/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. You do not have permission to access this page.

[Return to home page.](http://www.nyswda.org/devjom3update/)

function toggle( element ) { var className = element.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL before you select the Administration Console link.  Does it have a www or no www?  Is it http:// or https://?  Next, check the URL of the error page for the same things.  Is there a difference?  If so, that's your problem.  Check [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/network-error-unable-to-reach-the-server/3233#3233) for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

In civicrm common folder is missing. Check common folder is there or not