# Contribution view / edit error

Tags: contributions, admin

When I go to Contributions and click "View", I always got an error "*Erreur réseau. Impossible de joindre le serveur*" ("*Network error. Cannot join the server*" - in english).

I can't find any error in logs...

I run CiviCRM 4.6.6 under Wordpress 4.3.1. But got the same error with updated versions of both on another server.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found. In my case an extension was causing trouble : CDNTaxReceipt. Disabling it solved the problem.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you check that the Base URL in the CiviCRM settings file.

Look for CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in civicrm.settings.php file.

See this similar question for more details: [**Network Error - Unable to reach the server](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/network-error-unable-to-reach-the-server)

Comment: Thank you. For the moment I did not find a setting correcting my problem. I'll try a little more and tell you.

Comment: So, it's not workig. If I look at ajax called URL in the network inspector, domain is right.

If I enter this URL directly in my browser, it's OK

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view/contribution&reset=1&action=update&id=XX&cid=YY&context=dashboard&snippet=json

But if I replace "action=edit" with "action=view" : I get a 500 error...

/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view/contribution&reset=1&action=view&id=XX&cid=YY&context=dashboard&snippet=json

Comment: Have you set the Base URL for your site?  Does your site use example.com (no www) or www.example.com?  Do you use https?

Comment: Yes CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL is correctly set. I use http and www

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this error is wrong civicrm base url. (Most of the time it's happen due to www in base url. If your url does not contain www the don't use it in civicrm base url.)