# Problem with contribution - redirect to Home Page

Tags: contributions

I have two types of contribution page (for different purposes) one requires sign in and the other does not. 
When a user goes to go to either contribution page for the very first time and clicks on confirm payment, the system goes into an endless loop that ends up on the Home page.  If from there one goes to the  contribution page again, it works fine.

Any Ideas what could be causing this?  Oddly it does not happen when someone registers to an event.

Please any feedback is welcome, I need this fixed before the end of ther year.

Thank you

Edited:

I figured out the problem, but not yet the solution.  it has to do with the URL intial URL has www.xxxx.com once it is sent back to the Home page the URL is xxxx.com (no www)

the setting in the civicrm.settings.php does not have the www.  Is this right???  should it have the www???  any help is appreciated.

thank you

Comment: What CMS and Civi version? Any redirect plugins/modules installed on the CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!!!

CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL has to have www

Comment: For a full description of the problem and solution, check out http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/3233/44.  Basically, it's best to stick with only one address and set up redirects so that everyone uses that URL.

Comment: Jennifer - can you accept your own answer and keep SE happy