# Access denied when I want to "Display and Edit Custom Fields"

Tags: custom-fields

I have Access denied when : Administer > ... > Custom Data > Display and Edit Custom Fields

I notice that "www." is added between htpps:// and my site name :
https://bapa-lacellesaintcloud.com/drupal/index.php?q=civicrm/admin/custom/group&reset=1
is moved to :
https://www.bapa-lacellesaintcloud.com/drupal/index.php?q=civicrm/admin/custom/group/field&reset=1&action=browse&gid=1

... and I get the right form when I (manually) remove this "www." from the URL

Why (how ?) is this "www." added ?

BTW : I don't have this error on 2 test sites which are not https but only http ; All my sites have been upgraded to 4.7.2, but I am not sure that this problem was not there before.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/network-error-unable-to-reach-the-server/3233#3233).  Another possibility is that your web server has a rewrite that adds the www.  Another possibility is that there's an `.htaccess` file in your CMS's path that's adding a rewrite.

Comment: I think you are right : when I passed this site in HTTPS a colleage modified the .htaccess file (I am not able to do this by myself) and must have missed sthg ; I have to manage this with him, and will come back. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your settings file to ensure the base URLs are set correctly?  From the Civi 4.7 demo site I see that some changes have taken place in how those are handled (with tokens instead of direct references in the Resource URLs page): http://screencast.com/t/lYLFOtdqrkK